# Differential equation Steady state solution

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, steady-state

Hi I am looking for the steady state solution (stationnary solution independent of t when t grow to infinity) of the following equation:

$$ \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}$$
Initial condition: $u(x,0) = 0 $ and $u(0,t) = 0 $  and $u(1,t) = 1 $

I tried to separate the function $u$ like this $u(x,t) = f(x)g(t)$ to find a basis of solutions.

$$ \frac{g'}{g}(t) = \frac{f''}{f}(x)$$

gives me that both ratio are equal to the same constant $\lambda$ for all $x$ and $t$

$g(t)=ae^{\lambda t}$ and $f(x)=be^{x \sqrt \lambda } + ce^{-x \sqrt \lambda }$

$u(x,t)=ae^{\lambda t}(be^{x \sqrt \lambda } + ce^{-x \sqrt \lambda })$

$u(0,t) = 0 $ gives $b = -c$

From that I can not find any solution but the null function.

Could you help me find the steady state solution? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct, solutions are of the form

$$
\frac{g'(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{f''(x)}{f(x)} = \lambda
$$

However, the value of $\lambda$ could take different signs.

> $\lambda = \kappa^2 > 0$,

In this case

$$
g(x) = a e^{\kappa^2 t} ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ f(x) = b e^{\kappa t} + c e^{-\kappa t}
$$

so that

$$
u(x, t) = ae^{\kappa^2 t}(b e^{\kappa t} + c e^{-\kappa t})
$$

This solution will explode in the limit $t\to \infty$, unless $b=c = 0$

> $\lambda = -\kappa^2 < 0$

I will leave this case for you, but the idea is the same, this solution goes to zero in the long term

> $\lambda = 0$

For this case

$$
g(x) = a ~~~~\mbox{and}~~~ f(x) = bx + c
$$

The solution then has the form

$$
u(x, t) = Ax + B
$$

Now set the conditions

$$
u(0, t) = 0 = B ~~~\mbox{and}~~~ u(1, t) = 1 = A
$$

So the stationary solution is

$$
u(x, t) = x
$$

---

**EDIT**

There's a simpler solution to this: in the stationary case the solution does not depend on $t$, so we have the problem

$$
\frac{\partial^2 }{\partial x^2}u_{\rm stationary}(x) = 0
$$

whose solution is just

$$
u_{\rm stationary}(x) = A x + B
$$

with the boundary conditions we get

$$
u_{\rm stationary}(x) = x
$$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It is exactly what I was looking for. I think you confused $x$ and $t$ a few times but it is no big deal. 
Would you see a more straighforward way to come up with this stationary solution? The excercise structure let me believe there is a simplier way to achieve the stationary solution.

Comment: @MaxFt Yes, there's a simpler solution, see the edit

Comment: Why does the stationarity force the second derivative to be equal to 0?

Comment: @MaxFt Because the stationary solution will not depend on time, so 

$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} = 0 = \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
$$

Comment: I see thank you I’ll validate your answer

Comment: @MaxFt Happy to help